# JBoss AS 7 Error while deplouing EJBs

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ear

I am working through this deployment one step at a time.  Did get some answers from people that have helped but I am now stuck on this error:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.DoDSRDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."dodsr.ear/dodsr.jar#DoDSRMGR"]
```

My persistence.xml file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
  <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
         version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="DoDSRMGR">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DoDSRDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>mil.army.amedd.dodsr.model.ManifestsPass1</class>
    <class>mil.army.amedd.dodsr.model.ManifestsPass2</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="java:/DoDSRDS"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And the datasource in standalone.xml is this:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DoDSRDS" pool-name=" DoDSRDS " enabled="true" use-java-context="true">

<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@160.151.120.38:2115:apdb</connection-url>

<driver>oracle</driver>

<pool>

    <prefill>true</prefill>

    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>

</pool>

<security>

    <user-name>username</user-name>

    <password>password</password>

</security>
```

How do I get this thing to deploy??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be 2 potential problems:

- The name of the datasource in standalone.xml might be wrong or missing.
- You might need to change 
  `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DoDSRDS</jta-data-source>`
  in persistence.xml to
  `<jta-data-source>java:/DoDSRDS</jta-data-source>`.

I'd your main problem is number 2 but number 1 might still be true (you didn't provide the name definition in your post).

*Update:*

If you don't need to use the name `jboss/datasources/DoDSRDS` I'd suggest just using `DoDSRS`, i.e. `jndi-name="java:/DoDSRDS"` and `<jta-data-source>java:/DoDSRDS</jta-data-source>`.

*Update 2:*

A third problem *might* be the spaces in the `pool-name`. I'm not sure they're allowed here but at least it might cause problems if you reference the pool by name and don't have the exact same number of spaces, so I'd remove those in any case.

Comment: I edited the question to show that the datasource in standalone.xml does match that of the persistence.xml of:
    "java:jboss/datasources/DoDSRDS"

Comment: @Dean.DePue I'm not sure on the format, but `java:jboss` might be a problem (I can't look up the manual right now).

Comment: Strange bcuz that is the first thing I was told on the last question I posted that it should contain the reference to jboss/datasources in the naming.  Could the fact that, in persistence.xml, I have this: 
     <persistence-unit name="DoDSRMGR"> be the reason?

Comment: @Dean.DePue AFAI the persistence-unit name is irrelevant. I just saw that the tutorials state `java:jboss/datasources` so that might be fine. We're using `java:/DSName` and it works, so that at least should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but then why does the error refer to the missing dependents to DoDSRMGR.  Do I have to define this somewhere?  I am very new to this whole thing and am struggling to get it going with no help from anyone here.

Comment: @Dean.DePue I think you have a misunderstanding here, at least as far as I know. The message says that datasource `DoDSRS` is missing and `DoDSRMGR` depends on it and thus hasn't been started.

Comment: Thomas OK, I think I'm understanding a little bit more.  How do I start the datasource?  Or, more appropriately, how do I tell the administrator to start it since I do not have access to the JBoss server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55842/discussion-between-dean-depue-and-thomas).